# SSID was not declared in this scope

Tags: code-review, mkr1000, iot

so I am new to arduino and coding in general, I am trying to use the arduino to remotely survey plants, I am using this guide: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/arduino/plant-communicator-7ea06f. The entire code is:

```
#include <WiFi101.h>
#include<WiFiSSLClient.h>
const char* ssid = SKY1C9D0;    //  your network SSID (name)
const char* password = SYDTSTQR;  // your network password
String httpsRequest = https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/2821422/84ehn1/;     
// your Zapier URL
   const char* host = "hooks.zapier.com";
WiFiSSLClient client;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("Connecting Wifi: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  while (WiFi.begin(ssid, password) != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
}
void loop() {
  float temperature = 22;
  int moisture = 150;
  int light = 40;
  String warning = "This is a warning message";
  warning.replace(" ", "%20");
  send_email(temperature, moistue, light, warning );
  delay(20000)
}
void send_email(float temperature, int moisture, int light, String warning)     {
  // convert values to String
  String _temperature = String(temperature);
  String _moisture = String(moisture);
  String _light = String(light);
  String _warning = warning;
  if (client.connect(host, 443)) {
    client.println("POST " + httpsRequest + "temperature=" + _temperature +                 "&moisture=" + _moisture + "&light=" + _light + "&warning=" + _warning + "     HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: " + String(host));
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    delay(1000);
    while (client.available()) { // Print on the console the answer of the server
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.write(c);
    }
    client.stop();  // Disconnect from the server
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Failed to connect to client");
 }
}
```

The error is specifically highlighted here:
    `const char* ssid = SECRET_SSID;    //  your network SSID (name)`. The error is that the ssid has not been declared.
I am unsure of what to do to fix this and any other possible errors that have gone unnoticed. I would highly appreciate any help or guidance.
Thank you

Comment: `const char* ssid = "myAP";` and  `const char* password = "myAP passworld";` is not working? You have to REPLACE it with correct credentials.

Comment: I have tried using correct credentials, still does not work, I removed credentials only so I could post the code online

Comment: Also the `httpsRequest` have to be a string, you can't just put the https address like this.

Comment: have you replaced `SECRET_SSID` with the actual SSID or defined a value for a variable `SECRET_SSID`? The error seems to be saying that `SECRET_SSID` is not defined or declared so the compiler doesn't know what that text is. This looks like C so is there a #define missing?

Comment: I have now edited it with the actual ssid and password, it still does not work

Comment: @KIIV how would I include the https address then?

Comment: `String httpsRequest = "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/2821422/84ehn1/";`. However HTTP request should be GET, as you are not posting anything and Requested path should be without protocol and without host

Answer (score 1):

A problem in the include file on the line previous could cause the following line to be misinterpreted. To test that try moving the ssid after the password and see if the error changes. Obviously make sure all strings are properly quoted.

```
#include <WiFi101.h>
#include <WiFiSSLClient.h>

const char* password = "SYDTSTQR";  // your network password
const char* ssid = "SKY1C9D0";    //  your network SSID (name)
String httpsRequest = "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/2821422/84ehn1/";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around literal string values.

```
const char* ssid = "SKY1C9D0" ; // your network SSID (name)
const char* password = "SYDTSTQR" ;
```